# Function equation, find the function evaluated at the certain point.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients such that $f(0) = 1,$ $f(2)+f(3)=125,$ and for all $x$, $f(x)f(2x^{2})=f(2x^{3}+x).$ Find $f(5).$

The constant term, $a_0 = f(0) = 1$.

Let:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k$$

$f(2) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k 2^k$ and $f(3) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k 3^k$

$$f(1)f(2) = f(3)$$

But I have no clue. **Hints please, no complete answers!**

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but maybe you could analyse the zeros? If $f$ has a zero at $x$, then it has a zero at $2x^3 + x$. Like any non-zero polynomial, it can only have finitely many zeros, and the number of zeros is the degree, so the fewer there are, the fewer variables you need to deal with.

Comment: Where did you find this question?  Note that if $\alpha$ is a root, so is $2\alpha^3+\alpha$, which implies such a polynomial cannot have any roots or has infinite number of them!

Comment: @Macavity: Well, it shows that there are no real roots (since $0$ is out), which suggests the polynomial is of even degree.

Comment: @Macavity, http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2007_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_14 Insane problem

Comment: @Macavity: Well, there are finitely many roots, so if $\alpha$ is a root, and $T : z \mapsto 2z^3 + z$, then $T^n(\alpha)$ is a root for any integer $n \ge 0$. Pigeonhole principle tells us that the sequence $T^n(\alpha)$ must eventually become periodic. And, forgetting about the original question, that can happen. For example, the equation $T^2(x) = x$ is a polynomial of degree $9$:$$16x^9 + 24x^7 + 12x^5 + 4x^3 = 0.$$ and it has non-zero solutions.

Comment: @Macavity: Well, $2$ is not a root of a polynomial from the question, so the sequence $T^n{\alpha}$ need not be periodic (and, in fact, will not be). But, if we start with a (necessarily complex) root of the polynomial $f$, then $T^n(\alpha)$ is also a root of $f$, hence its range is finite, hence there exist $m > n$ such that $T^m(\alpha) = T^n(\alpha)$, and the pattern repeats at least every $m - n$ terms.

Comment: Let the answer be d. The function must be f(x)=e^(bx) such that e^(2b)+e^(3b)=125=x^2+x^3. Solving for x as c we see that e^(4b)+e^(6b)+2e^(5b)=125^2=c^4+c^6+2d. Then we find d.

Comment: @Adelafif  $e^{bx}$ is not a polynomial in $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps these steps make it clearer - as you specified giving only key steps, let me know if something needs more detail.

Let $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$. Immediately, $f(0)=1 \implies a_0 = 1$.

Next, from the functional equation, consider the coefficient of the highest power term on either side.  Show $a_n=1$.

From Vieta, now we have that the product of all roots is $\pm1$.  Argue from the functional equation and roots $r \to 2r^3+r$ that if any root has modulus other than $1$, there is a series of infinite roots.

So all roots have form $r = e^{i\theta}$ and $|2r^3+r| = 1$. Show this $\implies r = \pm i$.

Finally, as $f$ has real coefficients, it must be of form $f=(x^2+1)^{m}$ and the rest follows from computation.